# API not receiving data from AXIOS post request

Tags: javascript, api, post, axios

`Hi, I am trying to build an API which recives post requests from a React app that uses AXIOS. However, when I make the post request, my API doesn't appear to receive the data.

**Client**
`

```
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/resource',
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
            data: {
              username: 'Matt',
              password: 'Clifford'
          }}

        axios.request(options)
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.statusText);
            console.log(response.headers);
            console.log(response.config);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

`

**Server**
`

```
    app.route('/api/resource')
    .post(async (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.data)
    })
```

`

**Result**
`200 OK AxiosHeaders {content-length: '0'} {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1),     timeout: 0, …}`

Any help or advice is appreciated.

`

Comment: Maybe `req.body`?

Comment: Thanks @testing_22 but I have tried req.body too and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't using the correct middleware.

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Once I added this, it worked correctly.